# Need regex in C# to match street name for addresses like "123 101st ST"

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex string in C# to match street names where the addresses are like:

101 **2nd** St.
5 **1st** St.
4 & 5 **103rd** Ave.
88 **44th** St.

I need to identify where the street portion (e.g., 2nd,1st,103rd,44th) begins in an address string. I've successfully been able to locate the text portion in C# by using @"(1ST |RD |TH |ND )", but that doesn't give me where the numeric portion of the street name begins.

Any help would be cool. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a really bad idea, and not reliable at all.

Comment: So close, just tack on an appropriate pattern\capture for the number, eg. `(\d+)(ST|RD|TH|ND)` - Although I am sure this will break down, it meets the given data. The MatchInfo contains where each match starts. Anyway, have fun!

Comment: Are the street names guaranteed to be numerical avenues and streets? Or can they also be things like "Parkway" and "Broad"?

Comment: I just need to be able to identify if a numerical avenue or street is used; I already have a method for dealing with all the rest. The idea is to determine if and where a numerical street/avenue is used and if so, treat everything to the left of it as the street number.

Comment: user2864740, Thanks! That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the number portion for st, nd, rd and th you can use a lookahead regex:

```
(\d+)(?=ST|RD|TH|ND)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/aG4jV5/2)**

[image]

If you want the number including the string you can use:

```
(\d+(?:ST|RD|TH|ND))
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/aG4jV5/3)**

Comment: Thanks, Fede, this worked. I already had a regex based routine that would split a complex address into its various components (House#, Prefix, Street Name, Type, Suffix and Apartment#). Problem was we'd get stuff like "123 & 124 E Main St. ..." which would get split at the &. So I wrote a preprocessor that split the string at the 1st character that wasn't a number, space, ampersand or dash, then strip out the spaces to the left of that and add back the rest. So the example above became "123&124 E Main ..." and it split beautifully. Until I ran into something like "123 101st St ..."

Comment: This problem lends itself to accepting a high rate of false positive matches which isn't necessarily bad if your input source is either generated directly by you or you can otherwise count on a high level of consistency in it. Just to maybe cut down on that... if you are always expecting a space character before and after the each term in the address, then just put a "\s" before and after this regex sequence, and limit the \d to only 1-3 characters instead of just anything >=1 with: "\d{1,3}"

Comment: @theferrit32 I agree with you. Btw, OP commented that he has a preprocessor to generate it. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you known the data will always start with a number and end with some suffix like St. or Ave., maybe something like this?

`^(?<number>[0-9]+) (?<street>.*) (?<suffix>[^ ])$`

Chances are that you are working with real addresses though, in which case I doubt a regex exists that will handle all variations.